# Android Java Save State Between Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I would like to ask how I am going to save the state between the fragments while using bottom navigation. For example, if I am on "HomeFragment" and I go inside it with a "MovieDetailsFragment" and then I touch on "SettingsFragment" which is on the bottom navigation as "HomeFragment" and then I go back from SettingsFragment to HomeFragment I need to see the MovieDetailsFragment since I want to keep this state, instead of the fresh reloaded HomeFragment.

Now when I go from SettingsFraggment to HomeFragment, I am getting the fresh loaded HomeFragment instead of its inside fragment which is MovieDetailsFragment. This is a sign that the app is not storing any of this state.

Comment: How are you [saving your fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state)? How are you 'going back from SettingFragments to HomeFragment' - by pressing the bottom navigation button associated with the HomeFragment?

Comment: I am sending the details from HomeFragment to MovieDetailsFragment by bundle, but i need to save that action when I entered the MovieDetailsFragment from HomeFragment so when i go to SettingsFragment and then back to HomeFragment I will see the MovieDetailsFragment. Yes, I am moving between HomeFragment and SettingsFragment using the bottom navigation's buttons. In order to go to MovieDetailsFragment I need to be inside HomeFragment.